# Why is a single nonnegative number smaller than a sum of nonnegative numbers?

Tags: metric-spaces, real-numbers, axioms, peano-axioms

I know this sounds like an incredibly dumb question, but why is a single nonnegative number smaller than a sum of nonnegative numbers in a vector? I know it's true, but I want to know *why* it's true. Would it have to be due to the order topology or metric topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Example: $x = (1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5)$.

$1+0+2+3+4+0+5 = 15$.

One can see that any $x_i \in x$ is smaller than the sum of the entries of $x$. And there would be a $\leq$ if say, $x = (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$ or some other vector where the $x_i$ you chose was the only element in the vector. Hopefully what I'm saying here is clear.

But why specifically is it that any $x_i$ is less than the sum of all the elements in the vector?

edit: Ultimately, what I want to know is why is this the case.

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}^p, |x_i| \leq |\sum{x_i}|$.

I originally started my question by just positing that every number had to be nonnegative for the sake of simplicity, but in reality, what I want to know why is the case is this right here.

edit: I'm sorry for anybody that comes across this ridiculously stupid question. You know how sometimes you're working on a problem and it causes you to leap down rabbit holes and question things that you shouldn't because like, you already know them or something? Yeah. this was that. I'm just stupid. Sorry for wasting your time with this.

Comment: Are all the entries required to be non-negative?  If so, then of course the sum over a subset is $≤$ the sum of all the entries (since the sum over the complimentary set is non-negative).

Comment: @lulu, yes, sorry, I should have specified that aspect. Though I would be curious to know what the consequences would be if negativity was allowed. I'll make an edit.

Comment: $(-1,-2,-3)$ has the sum $-6$...

Comment: The sole reason this is true is that the reals satisfy the property that if $x\geq y$ and $a\geq b$, then $a+x\geq b+y$. Take $b=0$ and voila, $a\geq0$ ensures that $a+x\geq y$.

Comment: "Proving" "obvious" statements is always a little subtle: it matters more than usual to specify exactly what axioms we're working with (that is, what rules we're taking for granted). When we're "proving" something more complicated, we often gloss over this point since it's not really what we're interested in, but here it's the only thing that matters. So: what axioms are you using?

Comment: @DonThousand, hi, sorry, I added nonnegativity as I forgot to include that in my original posting. My post has been updated.

Comment: @DonThousand Well, we also need a tiny bit of induction to even make sense of arbitrary finite sums ... :P

Comment: @NoahSchweber Of course, but this is the agent of induction.

Comment: @DonThousand Sure, I'm being overly pedantic there - but it's a funny fact!

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Hi, well, admittedly I'm not entirely sure what axioms I would be using. The only requirement(s) I can think of are that each number in the vector is nonnegative and that addition is defined to be the standard addition of real numbers or just the natural numbers. I haven't ever really formally learned anything about the true fundamentals of set theory and stuff that happened at the turn of the 1900's and into the early 20th century. I use those results frequently, but as a result I don't know what axioms I can assume or not assume.

Comment: @MatthewGraham In that case, I think you need to do a bit more homework, eh? :P

Comment: @DonThousand, haha, well I actually am working on homework but I'm working on my statistics homework. The problem I'm working on is "Prove that $|x_i| \leq ||x||_2 \leq ||x||_1$. I know how to do the proof, but part of my proof involves showing for that first inequality that the sum of the elements of a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$ are greater than or equal to any particular element $x_i \in x$. In my proof I just say we know this is true and move on because, well, everybody knows it's the case, but now I've just jumped down a rabbit hole to satiate my own curiosity :P

Answer (score 1):

I tried to write a proof for this, wish it helps.

let $x_i$ be arbitrary nonegative integers such that $x_i \ge 0$ for all $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$.

let $s = x_1 +x_2 + \ldots +x_n$ be the sum of them.

$s - x_i = x_1 + \ldots + x_{i-1} + x_{i+1} + \ldots + x_n \ge 0$,
as $x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n \ge 0$.

$s - x_i \ge 0$, which means $s \ge x_i$.

Comment: You kinda just "proved" it by just stating the claim. That's not really a proof.

Comment: I edited your post, and added a missing inequality sign. I think the proof works now. The proof is based on the fact that a sum of non-negative reals is non-negative.